# React Native, Unhandled Rejection when writing to Firebase

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to get the id of the a new saved document in Firebase.

```
_saveQuoteToDB = async (text, author, quotes) => {
    docRef = await Firebase.db.collection('quotes').add({ text, author });
    quotes[quotes.lenght - 1].id = docRef.id;
  }
```

The new document is stored, I can cross check it online on the Firebase console.

But App (Web and Android) crashes with the following error:

[image]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the two errors

I missed a const statement - though I don't now why I need it. And of course ist length not lenght

```
_saveQuoteToDB = async (text, author, quotes) => {
    const docRef = await Firebase.db.collection('quotes').add({ text, author });
    quotes[quotes.length - 1].id = docRef.id;
}
```